# FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS for customizing status bar makes navigation bar overlapping

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I searched for a solution to set a drawable for status bar and I found this :

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    }
```

This code works fine but it makes another problem too!
If user's android device has bottom navigation buttons (software buttons) my layout goes behind it! of course this problem happens for top of my layouts too.
[You can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMc33.jpg)

Is there a way to have a customized status bar while there is no problem with other items overlapping my layout?

Comment: Have you found solution? I am having this issue on API 29+

Answer (score 2):

This code solved my problem!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    //make full transparent statusBar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

public static void setWindowFlag(Activity activity, final int bits, boolean on) {
    Window win = activity.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}
```